# Unable to start my virtual machine [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS] on VMWare player

Tags: vmware-player

I am currently a user of VMWare player to run the virtual machine for Ubuntu 12.04. Everything was working till today but after a restart I can no longer access the virtual machine.

It does not move ahead after the login page. I enter my login credentials and then it returns back again to the login page. No matter how many time I do this, it does not login. Same, If I try with the guest login.

The only thing that happened was that yesterday I did a lot of update to the ubuntu using sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get upgrade. Today, while performing some simple task the konsole was not responding I had to close it forcibly. On attempting to reopen konsole, it did not respond. While attempting to restart it said konsole in running but it did not show konsole. Like 2-3 times before, I just had to force quit the konsole and restart my virtual machine. After which, I am unable to login.

After I try to login, it shows a black screen of booting with a line at top saying "Checking battery state" and then comes back to login page but does not boot.

I am just using the free distribution of the VMWare player but not the workstation.

Would be great if someone could share there insight on this and suggest a solution.

Comment: Checking battery state is an odd thing for a VM to say. Also, you keep saying konsole - is this a KDE build of ubuntu?

Comment: This is the build with Unity desktop environment.